# How to track open() syscalls in FUSE filesystem?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, fuse

I want to track all open() syscalls of a process inside a FUSE filesystem.

Two concerns:

1. Is there any usecase, when open() syscall will not trigger a FUSE filesystem operation? For example syscall will be handled internally by kernel.
2. Which FUSE operations may be triggered after open() syscall? I've found those [in libfuse documentation](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a97243e0f9268a96236bc3b6f2bacee17):

   - open()
   - mknod() + create()
   - ... any other?

Edit: To add some context:

- I already have own FUSE filesystem, thus asking specifically for risks when this is implemented in FUSE.
- System should run constantly (as opposed to occasional debugging/analysis), so performance is important (`strace` has huge overhead cost).
- Should work for both static and dynamic executables -- thus libraries overriding open(), and injected as LD_PRELOAD are not a viable option.

Comment: `man strace` `man audit.rules`

Comment: Thanks. This does not answer my question, though. ;-) I specifically asked about how to do it in FUSE. strace requires modification of original command executed (thing needs to be prefixed with `strace`), thus is not convenient. Nevertheless, I'll take a deeper look into audit feature!

Comment: strace can attach to a running process

Comment: Of course, but `my-executable && strace -p $!` may already skip some syscalls.

Comment: You can try https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-25/opensnoop-for-linux.html